# svndumpfilter to extract specific folder from repository dump

Tags: windows, svn, windows-10, visualsvn-server, svnserve

I have visualsvn server with many repository.

One of the team requested to exract few folders from project repository, But I am stuck while extracting it.

Here is the structure.

```
E012345------------------Parenet_Folder
  |_____E012345-------------------Same_Parent_Folder_Name ( I dont why this folder was created)
          |______Main
         |______Working
```

Main and working are under E012345(Same as parent folder name)

I took the full dump of the repository, using command;

svnadmin dump E012345 > E012345_20191405.dump

and executed the below 2 commands for svndumpfilter, but it did not extract any data.

1. svndumpfilter include E012345/E012345/Main < D:\filter\E012345_20191405.dump > D:\Main.dump
2. svndumpfilter include E012345/Main < D:\filter\E012345_20191405.dump > D:\Main.dump

I know somewhere I am missing it. please help and guide me how  to extract it,

Answer (score 0):

1. Check *if anything* exist in full dump before filtering, because `svnadmin dump PATH` only must work, and even if E012345 is physical root of repository and you started dumping in it's parent, I'll expect to see `./E012345`
2. If you have data in dump, you can try to use `--prefix` for SVN 1.7+
3. I think, `svnrdump dump $URL` will be better choice anyway, because you can create dump of any subtree of repo in just one command

Comment: 1. Yes, data exist in dump, to verify, I created new repository and loaded it, its the same.  

2. --prefix is not available also tried --pattern it did not work, I have visualsvn 2.0.8 with 1.6.6 will check it by upgrading it.  

3. Yes, I took the dump by giving full path.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to extract using svndumpsanitizer tool.